# How can you get the first digit in an int (C#)?

Tags: c#, integer, substring, tostring

In C#, what's the best way to get the 1st digit in an int?

The method I came up with is to:

- turn the int into a string,
- get the 1st char of the string, and
- turn the char into an int.

Like:

```
int start = Convert.ToInt32(curr.ToString().Substring(0, 1));
```

While this does the job, it feels like there is probably a good, simple, math-based solution to such a problem. String manipulation feels clunky.

**Edit:**
Irrespective of speed differences, `mystring[0]` instead of `Substring()` is still just string manipulation

Comment: That's is even slower than the recursive method. =)

Comment: my bad, i forgot to reset the stopwatch =), it's really slower than others

Comment: This will fail on negative numbers.

Comment: the first digit of an int is always 1 with zero suppression (01010101010100101011011011100101)  LOL

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Here's how

```
int i = Math.Abs(386792);
while(i >= 10)
    i /= 10;
```

and `i` will contain what you need

Answer (score 232):

## Benchmarks

Firstly, you must decide on what you mean by "best" solution, of course that takes into account the efficiency of the algorithm, its readability/maintainability, and the likelihood of bugs creeping up in the future.  Careful unit tests can generally avoid those problems, however.

I ran each of these examples 10 million times, and the results value is the number of `ElapsedTicks` that have passed.

Without further ado, from slowest to quickest, the algorithms are:

### Converting to a string, take first character

```
int firstDigit = (int)(Value.ToString()[0]) - 48;
```

Results:

```
12,552,893 ticks
```

### Using a logarithm

```
int firstDigit = (int)(Value / Math.Pow(10, (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Value))));
```

Results:

```
9,165,089 ticks
```

### Looping

```
while (number >= 10)
    number /= 10;
```

Results:

```
6,001,570 ticks
```

### Conditionals

```
int firstdigit;
if (Value < 10)
     firstdigit = Value;
else if (Value < 100)
     firstdigit = Value / 10;
else if (Value < 1000)
     firstdigit = Value / 100;
else if (Value < 10000)
     firstdigit = Value / 1000;
else if (Value < 100000)
     firstdigit = Value / 10000;
else if (Value < 1000000)
     firstdigit = Value / 100000;
else if (Value < 10000000)
     firstdigit = Value / 1000000;
else if (Value < 100000000)
     firstdigit = Value / 10000000;
else if (Value < 1000000000)
     firstdigit = Value / 100000000;
else
     firstdigit = Value / 1000000000;
```

Results:

```
1,421,659 ticks
```

### Unrolled & optimized loop

```
if (i >= 100000000) i /= 100000000;
if (i >= 10000) i /= 10000;
if (i >= 100) i /= 100;
if (i >= 10) i /= 10;
```

Results:

```
1,399,788 ticks
```

**Note:**

each test calls `Random.Next()` to get the next `int`

Comment: Ran them on what set of integers?

Comment: I especially enjoy the fact that the unrolled loop wins. Elegant *and* performant.

Comment: I'm surprised the loop is so slow, is it much quicker to use while (number >= 10) {number /= 10;} I'm not convinced by Jared's argument the Microsoft might have a bug in integer division

Comment: John: well, what a dilemma. My benchmark (admittedly, on a different set of integers), shows that the loop is marginally faster than the conditionals version.

Comment: well the loop was tested with a subtraction, a modulo and a division, whereas only a single division is needed

Comment: Still, your code gives a order of magnitude of difference between the methods while mine is on par. How come?

Comment: I would have expected the loop to outperform the floating point method alright, thanks to all that time wasted on Project Euler problems :)

Comment: @Konrad - I actually was a bit too quick in posting this as I didn't use the PRNG for some of the methods, oops! I have updated the results again and I'm getting them consistently when running the test program.

Comment: @Konrad - I also wish I could explain the difference, it only makes sense that they should be similar... I've tried it on both debug and release configurations, but the results are similar

Comment: This is soooooo trivial.  I appreciate what you've done and it's quite informative, but it's so overkill for 99% of applications.  I'm afraid some novice programmers might get a bad impression. (hard-core, premature optimizations over readability)  It's still fun, though. :)

Comment: The while condition should be >= 10 on the loop.

Comment: +1 for benchmarks, but I agree this is total overkill. If you are THAT worried about performance then you probably shouldn't be using C# in the first place :)

Comment: +1 - Great stuff. This is the kind of gold-plated, deluxe-model overkill that just makes it obvious that you love coding. Many kudos to you. And no, Stuart, I don't think this will pollute the minds of unsuspecting newbies. Hopefully, it will teach them to develop a love of software.

Comment: Can you report on how much time was taken just to generate the random numbers, so that we can see what proportion was used doing the "real work" ?

Comment: Random() creates numbers linearly spread acrpooss the range. i.e. 90% of them will be >1000000000. so the "Conditionals" solution will make ~10 checks at average. just by reordering check order we can make it much faster

Comment: And if you will generate logarithm-linear numbers, the "Conditionals" solution probably will be faster too since it executes only one unpredicted jump, while the last solution performs 2 such jumps at average plus need to wait the division results after each successful "if". each unpredicted jump takes ~15 cycles, while predicted one is 0.5-1 cycle depending on the CPU

Comment: Hi John, Your solution is fine. I just wanted to know when you convert int to string and getting first value through index 0 after that you used -48. What is the use of -48 here? Can you explain?

Comment: @Vikash - casting a `char` to an `int` evaluates to the code point of the character, so casting the character `0` evaluates to 48. Subtracting 48 effectively does a conversion to an integer. As another example, casting the character `5` to an `int` evaluates to 53, and subtracting 48 from that results in 5.

Answer (score 31):

Try this

```
public int GetFirstDigit(int number) {
  if ( number < 10 ) {
    return number;
  }
  return GetFirstDigit ( (number - (number % 10)) / 10);
}
```

**EDIT**

Several people have requested the loop version

```
public static int GetFirstDigitLoop(int number)
{
    while (number >= 10)
    {
        number = (number - (number % 10)) / 10;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Recursion for something like this... Shame on you. Put a loop in there.

Comment: @Welbog :), Normally I would. But I have a lot of nostalgia around this particular question.  It almost exactly the first questions I was ever asked for a CS assignment.  At the time I wrote essentially this solution.

Comment: This is the case where "nice" = slow

Comment: I'd hope the optimizer would see the first version as something that can be tail-call optimized, in which case it wouldn't be any slower.

Comment: @rmeador, unfortunately you cannot always depend on the CLR to respect the .tail opcode.

Comment: @Welbog: shame on you. Why prefer the loop? No reason. Keltex: did you measure? Slow compared to what? … your solution? Surely not. Never heard of an optimizing compiler? This is such a trivial tail recursion, the compiler will blow it away completely.

Comment: But, @Jared, the subtraction of the last digit is completely unnecessary here. Just divide by 10.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "while (number >= 10)" like Anton's post?

Comment: @Konrad, C++ has made my very afraid of trusting the compiler / runtime to round properly in any scenario :).  Taking a look at the standards now because I'm curious what the CLR specifies for integer division.

Comment: <3 recursion, even when it doesn't make sense compared to an easy loop. +1 ;)

Answer (score 27):

The best I can come up with is:

```
int numberOfDigits = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor( Math.Log10( value ) ) );

int firstDigit = value / Math.Pow( 10, numberOfDigits );
```

Comment: You can avoid unneccesary conversions between integers and doubles by using divisor=Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(value)))); firstDigit = value/divisor;

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work when value is 1 (returns 0) or if value is negative.  The fix is  int numberOfDigits = 1 + Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(value))));

Answer (score 18):

variation on Anton's answer:

```
 // cut down the number of divisions (assuming i is positive & 32 bits)
if (i >= 100000000) i /= 100000000;
if (i >= 10000) i /= 10000;
if (i >= 100) i /= 100;
if (i >= 10) i /= 10;
```

Comment: I think I would just leave it at `/10` and `/1000`.  You still get the advantage of dividing more aggressively, but with slightly less mess.  +1 for creativity :)

Comment: Reminds me of a function in bcl someone discovered, the method was pretty ugly to read, but it was basically doing looping compares, and was ganging compares into groups of ten or so, knowing that modern cpus would be able to better handle a group of compares at a time.

Comment: It's only fantastically ugly because C# doesn't have a way to generate those consts at compile-time (and doing it at runtime would be more expensive than what you're trying to prevent).  In a language like Lisp where you control eval time, the fast way and the elegant way are the same.  :-)

Comment: Unrolling a loop is certainly better than a crap-ton of if/else statements. It's both elegant *and* performant.

Comment: if you make the first "if" a "while", it also works with 64-bit (but is even "uglier"). +1

Comment: @MartinStettner: Right, and not just anyone can write *really* ugly code :)

Answer (score 5):

```
int myNumber = 8383;
char firstDigit = myNumber.ToString()[0];
// char = '8'
```

Comment: Isn't this identical to what I posted? It just uses [] instead of Substring

Comment: No: it returns a character rather than a string and the [] lookup should be faster

Comment: That's true, but it's still the same basic method -- parse the string representation. I think @Dinah is looking for something... you know.... different.

Comment: @Randolpho: exactly. Sorry if I was unclear about that. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: I also would return firstDigit-'0' to get the int. (it works in c ... i guess it does in c#)

Answer (score 5):

Had the same idea as Lennaert

```
int start = number == 0 ? 0 : number / (int) Math.Pow(10,Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(number))));
```

This also works with negative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If you think Keltex's answer is ugly, try this one, it's REALLY ugly, and even faster.
It does unrolled binary search to determine the length.

```
 ... leading code along the same lines
/* i<10000 */
if (i >= 100){
  if (i >= 1000){
    return i/1000;
  }
  else /* i<1000 */{
    return i/100;
  }
}
else /* i<100*/ {
  if (i >= 10){
    return i/10;
  }
  else /* i<10 */{
    return i;
  }
}
```

P.S. MartinStettner had the same idea.

Comment: @Rasch: Ah, the rapture! It should be hidden, brought out for special occasions only, and read in hushed tones... Who says programming has no soul?

Comment: how about `i=(...moreugly...)i>=100?i>=1000?i/1000:i/100:i>=10?i/10:i;`

Answer (score 3):

Very simple (and probably quite fast because it only involves comparisons and one division):

```
if(i<10)
   firstdigit = i;
else if (i<100)
   firstdigit = i/10;
else if (i<1000)
   firstdigit = i/100;
else if (i<10000)
   firstdigit = i/1000;
else if (i<100000)
   firstdigit = i/10000;
else (etc... all the way up to 1000000000)
```

Comment: And then there's 10k, 100k, 1mil, 10mil, 100mil and so on?

Comment: I would do it this way. A lot more efficient than that recursive function.

Comment: This answer is the best of the bunch.

Comment: Efficiency bought at the expense of really really really ugly, repetitive, unmaintainable code. 

What if you had skipped a rank accidentally? Whoops.

Comment: You really should reorder those conditions so that the most likely are at the top...

Comment: If I were you I would delete this answer before you lose anymore rep.

Comment: Good idea. You'll earn a badge for it. :)

Comment: If he deletes this answer, I'm reposting it.  It's the best answer.

Comment: I'm not deleting it. I'll let my rep go to 0.

Comment: Classic example of premature optimisation BTW

Comment: @Patrick McDonald: if you're referring to my original question -- I'm not trying to optimize at all. Just trying to learn. I'm a self-taught programmer which means I missed out on all the rigorous math education that CS majors get. I want to learn how to not lean on string manip. for everything.

Comment: I have an even faster version!  How about if (i == 1) return 1; if (i == 2) return 2; if (i == 3) return 3; //... and so on

Comment: @Dinah, the comment was to the answer I commented on, not to you :)

Comment: I think it is useful to be reminded that 'int' is a small finite datatype and that little tricks like this are there to be had.  The question asks for an alternative to the 'obvious' solution, and I think this is a great 'alternative' answer.  MO.  Anyway, I downvoted all the other answers.  Fun!

Comment: Here's an alternative:. Step 1) Post question on stackoverflow.com "What's the first digit of X?" Step 2) Wait 30 minutes and check the top answer.

Comment: @Brian: how mature (although most of the other answers contain small errors). This answer here *would* be interesting *if* it were correct, complete, with an explanation and a supporting benchmark. As it is, it's simply inaccurate and generally bad advice.

Comment: @Keltex "Step 1...": of course this is what I'm doing. Not sure how to be more clear. As could be said for any question on SO. But it doesn't mean I didn't try to solve it myself first.

Comment: @Dinah... my comment wasn't directed towards you. Your question was good!

Comment: I would have voted it up if he had written it in assembly, but I'm afraid that C# solutions are just too slow to justify their use!

Comment: You could improve it by doing a binary search over the range of integers or even reverse th order: There are much more integers with 12 digits than with 1, so it would be better to check them first. Of course that depends on the expected distribution of input values ...

Comment: Just to give my 2 cents: The task of finding the first decimal digit is well defined and is unlikely to change. This solution can be easily tested and will not need to be maintained. If performance is critical, I would consider using it. +1

Comment: "If I were you I would delete this answer before you lose anymore rep." Only 1 upvote needs to be gained for every 5 down -- which it is and then some. Keltex is gaining reputation for this.

Comment: This is totally wrong. You really should use select case instead of all those if-elseifs.

Comment: +1. What's the beef? In terms of performance, it trades subtractions for divisions compared to my answer. In terms of looks, I may not *like* to read it, but nobody can tell me they *can't* read it.

Answer (score 3):

```
int temp = i;
while (temp >= 10)
{
    temp /= 10;
}
```

Result in `temp`

Comment: @ck: What rounding issued? Division is integer-division in this case, each division exactly cuts off the last digit ...

Answer (score 3):

An obvious, but slow, mathematical approach is:

```
int firstDigit = (int)(i / Math.Pow(10, (int)Math.Log10(i))));
```

Comment: Time it, it shouldn't be slow at all.  This was going to be my suggestion, and given that it's a purely mathematical solution with no looping, it's possibly faster than many solutions here.  Keep in mind that every x86 processor sold today has a very, very fast and capable floating point processor.

Comment: I think you really should use Math.Log10 here

Comment: Thanks, Martin - I don't use .NET math libraries much and forgot it was Log and Log10 instead of Log and Ln.

Comment: Well, Adam, at the very least it needs to take 10^(N-1) (n being number of digits) plus it needs to take a logarithm.  Compared to a looping answer (where you're dividing N - 1 times) it seems to me that it must be at least a little slower.  But I am regularly surprised by benchmarks, so who knows.

Comment: Besides, the OP asked for a more meaningful expression, without regard to performance, and this is the most direct (mathematical) way to express what is being sought.

Comment: I agree.  I would personally use this in my own code (simply looking at the variable name makes it clear what's going on.)

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not C#, but it's surprising curious that in python the "get the first char of the string representation of the number" is the faster!

*EDIT*: no, I made a mistake, I forgot to construct again the int, sorry. The unrolled version it's the fastest.

```
$ cat first_digit.py
def loop(n):
    while n >= 10:
        n /= 10
    return n

def unrolled(n):
    while n >= 100000000: # yea... unlimited size int supported :)
        n /= 100000000
    if n >= 10000:
        n /= 10000
    if n >= 100:
        n /= 100
    if n >= 10:
        n /= 10
    return n

def string(n):
    return int(str(n)[0])
$ python -mtimeit -s 'from first_digit import loop as test' \
    'for n in xrange(0, 100000000, 1000): test(n)'
10 loops, best of 3: 275 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'from first_digit import unrolled as test' \
    'for n in xrange(0, 100000000, 1000): test(n)'
10 loops, best of 3: 149 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'from first_digit import string as test' \
    'for n in xrange(0, 100000000, 1000): test(n)'
10 loops, best of 3: 284 msec per loop
$
```

Comment: But does it convert it back to an integer?

Comment: woops, now it makes a sense -.-

Comment: well he could say it was IronPython to make this slightly less off-topic

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled upon this old question and felt inclined to propose another suggestion since none of the other answers so far returns the correct result for ***all*** possible input values and it can still be made faster:

```
public static int GetFirstDigit( int i )
{
    if( i < 0 && ( i = -i ) < 0 ) return 2;
    return ( i < 100 ) ? ( i < 1 ) ? 0 : ( i < 10 )
            ? i : i / 10 : ( i < 1000000 ) ? ( i < 10000 )
            ? ( i < 1000 ) ? i / 100 : i / 1000 : ( i < 100000 )
            ? i / 10000 : i / 100000 : ( i < 100000000 )
            ? ( i < 10000000 ) ? i / 1000000 : i / 10000000
            : ( i < 1000000000 ) ? i / 100000000 : i / 1000000000;
}
```

This works for all signed integer values inclusive `-2147483648` which is the smallest signed integer and doesn't have a positive counterpart. `Math.Abs( -2147483648 )` triggers a `System.OverflowException` and `- -2147483648` computes to `-2147483648`.

The implementation can be seen as a combination of the advantages of the two fastest implementations so far. It uses a binary search and avoids superfluous divisions. A quick benchmark with the index of a loop with 100,000,000 iterations shows that it is twice as fast as the currently fastest implementation.

It finishes after **2,829,581** ticks.

For comparison I also measured a corrected variant of the currently fastest implementation which took **5,664,627** ticks.

```
public static int GetFirstDigitX( int i )
{
    if( i < 0 && ( i = -i ) < 0 ) return 2;
    if( i >= 100000000 ) i /= 100000000;
    if( i >= 10000 ) i /= 10000;
    if( i >= 100 ) i /= 100;
    if( i >= 10 ) i /= 10;
    return i;
}
```

The accepted answer with the same correction needed **16,561,929** ticks for this test on my computer.

```
public static int GetFirstDigitY( int i )
{
    if( i < 0 && ( i = -i ) < 0 ) return 2;
    while( i >= 10 )
        i /= 10;
    return i;
}
```

Simple functions like these can easily be proven for correctness since iterating all possible integer values takes not much more than a few seconds on current hardware. This means that it is less important to implement them in a exceptionally readable fashion as there simply won't ever be the need to fix a bug inside them later on.

Answer (score 1):

Did some tests with one of my co-workers here, and found out most of the solutions don't work for numbers under 0.

```
  public int GetFirstDigit(int number)
    {
        number = Math.Abs(number); <- makes sure you really get the digit!

        if (number < 10)
        {
            return number;
        }
        return GetFirstDigit((number - (number % 10)) / 10);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using all the examples below to get this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Benfords
{
    class Program
    {
        static int FirstDigit1(int value)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString().Substring(0, 1));
        }

        static int FirstDigit2(int value)
        {
            while (value >= 10) value /= 10;
            return value;
        }


        static int FirstDigit3(int value)
        {
            return (int)(value.ToString()[0]) - 48;
        }

        static int FirstDigit4(int value)
        {
            return (int)(value / Math.Pow(10, (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(value))));
        }

        static int FirstDigit5(int value)
        {
            if (value < 10) return value;
            if (value < 100) return value / 10;
            if (value < 1000) return value / 100;
            if (value < 10000) return value / 1000;
            if (value < 100000) return value / 10000;
            if (value < 1000000) return value / 100000;
            if (value < 10000000) return value / 1000000;
            if (value < 100000000) return value / 10000000;
            if (value < 1000000000) return value / 100000000;
            return value / 1000000000;
        }

        static int FirstDigit6(int value)
        {
            if (value >= 100000000) value /= 100000000;
            if (value >= 10000) value /= 10000;
            if (value >= 100) value /= 100;
            if (value >= 10) value /= 10;
            return value;
        }

        const int mcTests = 1000000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch lswWatch = new Stopwatch();
            Random lrRandom = new Random();

            int liCounter;

            lswWatch.Start();
            for (liCounter = 0; liCounter < mcTests; liCounter++)
                FirstDigit1(lrRandom.Next());
            lswWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Test {0} = {1} ticks", 1, lswWatch.ElapsedTicks);

            lswWatch.Reset();
            lswWatch.Start();
            for (liCounter = 0; liCounter < mcTests; liCounter++)
                FirstDigit2(lrRandom.Next());
            lswWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Test {0} = {1} ticks", 2, lswWatch.ElapsedTicks);

            lswWatch.Reset();
            lswWatch.Start();
            for (liCounter = 0; liCounter < mcTests; liCounter++)
                FirstDigit3(lrRandom.Next());
            lswWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Test {0} = {1} ticks", 3, lswWatch.ElapsedTicks);

            lswWatch.Reset();
            lswWatch.Start();
            for (liCounter = 0; liCounter < mcTests; liCounter++)
                FirstDigit4(lrRandom.Next());
            lswWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Test {0} = {1} ticks", 4, lswWatch.ElapsedTicks);

            lswWatch.Reset();
            lswWatch.Start();
            for (liCounter = 0; liCounter < mcTests; liCounter++)
                FirstDigit5(lrRandom.Next());
            lswWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Test {0} = {1} ticks", 5, lswWatch.ElapsedTicks);

            lswWatch.Reset();
            lswWatch.Start();
            for (liCounter = 0; liCounter < mcTests; liCounter++)
                FirstDigit6(lrRandom.Next());
            lswWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Test {0} = {1} ticks", 6, lswWatch.ElapsedTicks);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I get these results on an AMD Ahtlon 64 X2 Dual Core 4200+ (2.2 GHz):

```
Test 1 = 2352048 ticks
Test 2 = 614550 ticks
Test 3 = 1354784 ticks
Test 4 = 844519 ticks
Test 5 = 150021 ticks
Test 6 = 192303 ticks
```

But get these on a AMD FX 8350 Eight Core (4.00 GHz)

```
Test 1 = 3917354 ticks
Test 2 = 811727 ticks
Test 3 = 2187388 ticks
Test 4 = 1790292 ticks
Test 5 = 241150 ticks
Test 6 = 227738 ticks
```

So whether or not method 5 or 6 is faster depends on the CPU, I can only surmise this is because the branch prediction in the command processor of the CPU is smarter on the new processor, but I'm not really sure.

I dont have any Intel CPUs, maybe someone could test it for us?

Answer (score 1):

Check this one too:

```
int get1digit(Int64 myVal)
{
    string q12 = myVal.ToString()[0].ToString();
    int i = int.Parse(q12);
    return i;
}
```

Also good if you want multiple numbers:

```
int get3digit(Int64 myVal) //Int64 or whatever numerical data you have
{
    char mg1 = myVal.ToString()[0];
    char mg2 = myVal.ToString()[1];
    char mg3 = myVal.ToString()[2];
    char[] chars = { mg1, mg2, mg3 };
    string q12= new string(chars);
    int i = int.Parse(q12);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Could your add some explanation to your answer? This question already has 24 other answers - it'd be good to know why we should use yours rather than the others.

Comment: With the original solution, i got some bugs using large numbers. My solution is cleaner. You're welcome.

Comment: Your solution fails for `-1`.

Comment: :) use this then :
if (myVal.ToString()[0]!='-')
            {....}
and - sign is not a number !

Comment: Why not check the number is not negative instead of checking the string?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an alternative, you could repeatedly divide the integer by 10, and then rollback one value once you reach zero. Since string operations are generally slow, this may be faster than string manipulation, but is by no means elegant.

Something like this:

```
while(curr>=10)
     curr /= 10;
```

Comment: Make the while-condition (curr > 10) and you do not need prevValue

Comment: >= is needed. The first digit of 10 should be 1, not 10

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i > 10)
{
   i = (Int32)Math.Floor((Decimal)i / 10);
}
// i is now the first int
```

Comment: Why are you converting to Decimal? Also Floor is not needed.

Comment: It was there for potential rounding issues, which isn't actually needed.

Comment: Should be while(i >= 10) or this will fail for multiples of 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
start = getFirstDigit(start);   
public int getFirstDigit(final int start){
    int number = Math.abs(start);
    while(number > 10){
        number /= 10;
    }
    return number;
}
```

or

```
public int getFirstDigit(final int start){
  return getFirstDigit(Math.abs(start), true);
}
private int getFirstDigit(final int start, final boolean recurse){
  if(start < 10){
    return start;
  }
  return getFirstDigit(start / 10, recurse);
}
```

Comment: Should work now. Also added recursive function with trap for abs.

Answer (score 0):

```
int start = curr;
while (start >= 10)
  start /= 10;
```

This is more efficient than a ToString() approach which internally must implement a similar loop and has to construct (and parse) a string object on the way ...

Answer (score 0):

Non iterative formula:

```
public static int GetHighestDigit(int num)
{
    if (num <= 0)
       return 0; 

    return (int)((double)num / Math.Pow(10f, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(num))));
}
```

Comment: Implementation of Log is iterative as it requires a root-finding algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Very easy method to get the Last digit:

```
int myInt = 1821;

int lastDigit = myInt - ((myInt/10)*10); // 1821 - 1820 = 1
```

Comment: That's nice, but the question is to get the First digit, not the Last.

Comment: @Daniel Because `int lastDigigt = myInt % 10;` is just too obvious?

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 4567789;
int digit1 = int.Parse(i.ToString()[0].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do ,please refer my function  below :

This function can extract first number occurance from any string you can modify and use this function according to your usage

```
   public static int GetFirstNumber(this string strInsput)
    {
        int number = 0;
        string strNumber = "";
        bool bIsContNo = true;
        bool bNoOccued = false;

        try
        {
            var arry = strInsput.ToCharArray(0, strInsput.Length - 1);

            foreach (char item in arry)
            {
                if (char.IsNumber(item))
                {
                    strNumber = strNumber + item.ToString();

                    bIsContNo = true;

                    bNoOccued = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    bIsContNo = false;
                }

                if (bNoOccued && !bIsContNo)
                {
                    break;
                }


            }

            number = Convert.ToInt32(strNumber);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return 0;
        }

        return number;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public static int GetFirstDigit(int n, bool removeSign = true) 
{
   if (removeSign)
      return n <= -10 || n >= 10 ? Math.Abs(n) % 10 : Math.Abs(n);
   else 
      return n <= -10 || n >= 10 ? n % 10 : n;
}

//Your code goes here
int[] test = new int[] { -1574, -221, 1246, -4, 8, 38546};
            
foreach(int n in test)                 
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", n, GetFirstDigit(n)));
```

Output:

-1574 : 4

-221 : 1

1246 : 6

-4 : 4

8 : 8

38546 : 6

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simpler way that does not involve looping

```
int number = 1234
int firstDigit = Math.Floor(number/(Math.Pow(10, number.ToString().length - 1))
```

That would give us 1234/Math.Pow(10, 4 - 1) = 1234/1000 = 1

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'.