# Convert double to String with fixed width

Tags: c++, string-formatting

I want to convert a double to string with fixed width.

If the width is 10, then I want the double value to get round off to this width.

For example, if value = 102.121323435345 and width is 10, then this value should be,

```
position==>        0123456789       
           value = 102.121323
```

I can achieve this with snprintf, but I am looking for a c++ native code to do the same.

```
char buf[125];
snprint(buf, width, "%.6f", value);
```

I tried to use the below, but it does not help me much,

```
 
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::fixed << std::setw(10) << std::precision(6) << value;
```

std::setw guarantiees the minimum width for the value and if the value is more than the width size, it does not round off the values.

Thanks.

Comment: Something that is not entirely clear to me: are you trying to print with a width of 10 like in your example output, or 4 decimal places, like in your c code?

Comment: Why are you against using snprintf?  It's perfectly valid c++.  The ostringstream is overkill for this.

Comment: @Martin, I want the width to be constant always

Answer (score 3):

You can use [osteram::width](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/width) and [ostream::precision](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/precision) function to achieve your goal, like this

```
std::ostringstream out;
out.width(10);
out.precision(10);
out << 123.12345678910111213;
```

Although it won't add zeros after the point in order to respect width but it will add spaces (or any character of you choise) before the number. So You'll get '       102' or '0000000102' (if you call out.fill('0');) instead of '102.000000' if you pass 102 as a input value.

Answer (score 2):

How about lexical cast?

```
double x = 102.1213239999;
std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(x).substr(0,10);
```

Its not exactly what you asked for. I was just trying to think outside the box.
You may also want to look at this question for a discussion on formatting [differences between C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119098/which-i-o-library-do-you-use-in-your-c-code/119194) and check out the [Boost Format Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/format/doc/format.html)

Comment: This is wrong.  Consider this number:

double x = 12345678901.

Your answer is going to be off by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Even though the example is wrong, the suggestion to look at the Boost Format library is worth a +1.

Comment: @unknown: I find absolute statements are usually wrong (this is probably not a good solution). I know that big values will be truncated, but the question is about fitting the data into a fixed size output field not accuracy (otherwise the solution is trivial use the manipulator width(10) ). In the original question snprint() is used to truncate the output, this alternative provides an equivalent (but neater) solution in C++. The real question is what do you do when you have a fixed size output field and the value is larger! This is why width(x) specifies a minimum width not a maximum width.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want? Here, we calculate the amount of available precision and set ostream accordingly.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    // Input
    double value =  102.1213239999;
    // Calculate limits
    int digits = ( (value<1) ? 1 : int(1+log10(double(abs(value)))) );
    int width = 10;
    int precision = (((width-digits-1)>=0) ? (width-digits-1):0);

    // Display
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.precision(precision);
    cout<<setw(10)<<value<<endl;


    return 0;

    }
    OUTPUT: 102.121324
```

Btw, if you want a truckload of ways to compute **digits**, [here's how.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489830/efficient-way-to-determine-number-of-digits-in-an-integer)

Comment: OP wants maximum output of 10 chars with maximum precision.

Comment: What happens when value > 1e9?

Comment: How about now? It will not stay at 10 chars if it's greater than 1e9 but the precision problem is resolved (I think).

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    double x=3.543732;
    cout << to_string(x).substr(0,5);
    return 0;
}
```