# Get the number of digits in an int

Tags: c++, c

How do I detect the length of an integer? In case I had le: int test(234567545);

How do I know how long the int is? Like telling me there is 9 numbers inside it???

*I have tried:**

```
char buffer_length[100];


    //  assign directly to a string.

    sprintf(buffer_length, "%d\n", 234567545);

    string sf = buffer_length;


    cout <<sf.length()-1 << endl;
```

But there must be a simpler way of doing it or more clean...

Comment: Just a thought: How should negative numbers be handled?

Comment: Why do you need `std::string` here? You could just do a `strlen(buffer_length)`. You also don't need the `\n` and thus no `-1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489830/efficient-way-to-determine-number-of-digits-in-an-integer

Comment: C and C++ are different programming languages. A number does not have digits, only its decimal representation has digits.

Comment: Simple, use the `snprintf()` trick, `int needed = snprintf (NULL, 0, "%d", 234567545);` See [man 3 printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) Under "RETURN VALUE" second paragraph second sentence specifically.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

How about division:

```
int length = 1;
int x = 234567545;
while ( x /= 10 )
   length++;
```

or use the [`log10`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/log10/) method from `<math.h>`.

**Note** that `log10` returns a `double`, so you'll have to adjust the result.

Comment: Thanks! :) just what i need to know

Comment: Note, `log(0)` is –infinity and converting that to an integer is UB.

Answer (score 11):

Make a function :

```
int count_numbers ( int num) {
   int count =0;
   while (num !=0) {   
      count++;  
      num/=10;
   } 
   return count;
}
```

Comment: I think we can add a simple if before while

Comment: Your function works, but .. ..little late.. anyway that dont hold me from giving you +1!

Comment: If `num==0` then it should return `1` since it has one digit.

Answer (score 9):

Nobody seems to have mentioned converting it to a string, and then getting the length.  Not the most performant, but it definitely does it in one line of code :)

```
int num = -123456;
int len = to_string(abs(num)).length();

cout << "LENGTH of " << num << " is " << len << endl;    
// prints "LENGTH of 123456 is 6"
```

Comment: just check negative values ;)

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd - lol.. you/re right... Make that `int len = to_string(abs(num)).length();`

Comment: "Nobody seems to have mentioned" — other than the original poster, you mean? :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `stringstream` for this as shown below

```
stringstream ss;
int i = 234567545;
ss << i;
cout << ss.str().size() << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

if "i" is the integer, then

```
int len ;

char buf[33] ;

itoa (i, buf, 10) ; // or maybe 16 if you want base-16 ?

len = strlen(buf) ;

if(i < 0)
    len-- ;    // maybe if you don't want to include "-" in length ?
```

Comment: `buf[12]` should be enough (at most 10 digits + sign + '\0').

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    int i=2384995;
    char buf[100];

    itoa(i, buf, 10); // 10 is the base decimal

    printf("Lenght: %d\n", strlen(buf));


    return 0;
}
```

Beware that itoa is not a standard function, even if it is supported by many compilers.

Comment: `buf[12]` should be enough (at most 10 digits + sign + '\0').

Answer (score 2):

len=1+floor(log10(n));//c++ code lib (cmath)

Comment: Why no love for poor number `0`?

Answer (score 1):

looking across the internet it's common to make the mistake of initializing the counter variable to 0 and then entering a pre-condition loop testing for as long as the count does not equal 0. a do-while loop is perfect to avoid this.

```
    unsigned udc(unsigned u) //unsigned digit count
    {
      unsigned c = 0;
      do
        ++c;
      while ((u /= 10) != 0);
      return c;
    }
```

it's probably cheaper to test whether **u** is less than **10** to avoid the uneccessary division, increment, and cmp instructions for cases where **u** < **10**.

but while on that subject, optimization, you could simply test **u** against constant powers of **ten**.

```
    unsigned udc(unsigned u) //unsigned digit count
    {
      if (u < 10)   return 1;
      if (u < 100)  return 2;
      if (u < 1000) return 3;
      //...
      return 0; //number was not supported
    }
```

which saves you **3** instructions per digit, but is less adaptable for different radixes inaddition to being not as attractive, and tedious to write by hand, in which case you'd rather write a routine to write the routine before inserting it into your program. because C only supports very finite numbers, **64bit**,**32bit**,**16bit**,**8bit**, you could simply limit yourself to the maximum when generating the routine to benefit all sizes.

to account for negative numbers, you'd simply **negate** **u** if **u** < **0** before counting the number of digits. of course first making the routine support **signed** numbers.

if you know that **u** < **1000**,
it's probably easier to just write, instead of writing the routine.

```
   if (u > 99) len = 3;
   else
   if (u > 9)  len = 2;
   else        len = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few different **C++** implementations<sup>*</sup> of a function named `digits()` which takes a `size_t` as argument and returns its number of digits. If your number is negative, you are going to have to pass its absolute value to the function in order for it to work properly:

#### The While Loop

```cpp
int digits(size_t i)
{
    int count = 1;
    while (i /= 10) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

#### The Exhaustive Optimization Technique

```cpp
int digits(size_t i) {
    if (i > 9999999999999999999ull) return 20;
    if (i > 999999999999999999ull) return 19;
    if (i > 99999999999999999ull) return 18;
    if (i > 9999999999999999ull) return 17;
    if (i > 999999999999999ull) return 16;
    if (i > 99999999999999ull) return 15;
    if (i > 9999999999999ull) return 14;
    if (i > 999999999999ull) return 13;
    if (i > 99999999999ull) return 12;
    if (i > 9999999999ull) return 11;
    if (i > 999999999ull) return 10;
    if (i > 99999999ull) return 9;
    if (i > 9999999ull) return 8;
    if (i > 999999ull) return 7;
    if (i > 99999ull) return 6;
    if (i > 9999ull) return 5;
    if (i > 999ull) return 4;
    if (i > 99ull) return 3;
    if (i > 9ull) return 2;
    return 1;  
}
```

#### The Recursive Way

```cpp
int digits(size_t i) { return i < 10 ? 1 : 1 + digits(i / 10); }
```

#### Using `snprintf()` as a Character Counter

⚠ Requires `#include <stdio.h>` and may incur a significant performance penalty compared to other solutions. This method capitalizes on the fact that [`snprintf()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) counts the characters it discards when the buffer is full. Therefore, with the right arguments and format specifiers, we can force `snprintf()` to give us the number of digits of any `size_t`.

```cpp
int digits(size_t i) { return snprintf (NULL, 0, "%llu", i); }
```

#### The Logarithmic Way

⚠ Requires `#include <cmath>` and is unreliable for unsigned integers with more than 14 digits.

```cpp
// WARNING! There is a silent implicit conversion precision loss that happens
// when we pass a large int to log10() which expects a double as argument.
int digits(size_t i) { return !i? 1 : 1 + log10(i); }
```

---

#### Driver Program

You can use this program to test any function that takes a `size_t` as argument and returns its number of digits. Just replace the definition of the function `digits()` in the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
using std::cout;
using namespace std::chrono;

// REPLACE this function definition with the one you want to test.
int digits(size_t i)
{
    int count = 1;
    while (i /= 10) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

// driver code
int main ()
{
    const int max = digits(~0ull);
    size_t i = 0, d;
    do {
        auto t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        d = digits(i);
        auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        duration<double, std::nano> te = t1 - t0;
        cout << i << " has " << d << " digits (" << te.count() << " ns).\n";
        i = d < max ? (!i ? 9 : 10 * i - 1) : ~0ull;
        t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        d = digits(i);
        t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        te = t1 - t0;
        cout << i << " has " << d << " digits (" << te.count() << " ns).\n";
    } while (++i);
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Everything was tested on a Windows 10 (64-bit) machine using GCC 12.2.0 in Visual Studio Code.</sub>

Comment: What is the result? Which is the fastest?

Comment: @TomTom I have modified the driver code to display the time it takes for the function to return the number of digits. I wasn't able to find out which is the fastest.  Can you tell me your use case?

Comment: I need to count the digit from a function, which the result is a float. 10'000 random values, range between FLOAT_MAX.. FLOAT_MIN.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are mixing C stdio and C++ iostream, you can use the `snprintf` `NULL` `0` trick to get the number of digits in the integer representation of the number. Specifically, per [man 3 printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) If the string exceeds the size parameter provided and is truncated `snprintf()` will return

> ```
>    ... the number of characters (excluding the terminating null byte)
>    which would have been written to the final string if enough space
>    had been available.
> ```

This allows `snprintf()` to be called with the `str` parameter `NULL` and the `size` parameter `0`, e.g.

```c
    int ndigits = snprintf (NULL, 0, "%d", 234567545)
```

In your case where you simply wish to output the number of digits required for the representation, you can simply output the return, e.g.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {

  std::cout << "234567545 is " << snprintf (NULL, 0, "%d", 234567545) <<
               " characters\n";

}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/snprintf_trick
234567545 is 9 characters
```

**note:** the downside to using the `snprintf()` trick is that you must provide the conversion specifier which will limit the number of digits representable. E.g `"%d"` will limit to `int` values while `"%lld"` would allow space for `long long` values. The C++ approach using `std::stringstream` while still limited to numeric conversion using the `<<` operator handles the different integer types without manually specifying the conversion. Something to consider.

**second note:** you shouldn't dangle the `"\n"` of the end of your `sprintf()` conversion. Add the new line as part of your output and you don't have to subtract `1` from the length...