# In C++, wrong result in the counting of the number of digits, converting to string and using .length()

Tags: c++, string, syntax

I need to count the number of digits in an integer number.

My approach is to turn the number into a string, and then count the characters in the string.

I have the correct result if I do this "step by step", with intermediate variables:

```
#include <string>

float videoLengthMs = 123456;

int cielo = std::ceil(videoLengthMs);

std::string pippo = (std::to_string(cielo));

int charnm = pippo.length();
```

but if I try to compute it all at once, I have the wrong result:

```
#include <string>

float videoLengthMs = 123456;

int charnm = (std::to_string(std::ceil(videoLengthMs))).length();
```

I am novice in C++, and I think I am doing something wrong with the syntax, but I can't see what is it.

(N.B. here for consistency I have defined the variable `videoLengthMs`, as a float; in my code this variable is the result of a division, and this is the reason why I consider it a float and I compute the ceiling first)

Comment: Because the second one misses casting `std::ceil` to `int`.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to be using floating point functions for this.  Do not use floating point functions for integer-based problems.

Comment: For anyone that's interested, [I benchmarked the different ways to calculate this](https://quick-bench.com/q/8R_wOggd7N_AgFkYbFQPoozbPW8) (string vs integer math vs floating point math)

Comment: @perivesta: I would first check they all return the same values... (which at least not the case for `0.f`). 1 versus 0...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result if `std::ceil(videoLengthMs)` is a `float`.
In the first version, you store that result in an `int`, truncating it.
In the second version, you pass the float value directly to `std::to_string`, which results in `"123456.000000"`, which is of course a lot longer than the string `"123456"` that you get from the `int` value. You can cast the result of `std::ceil` to an `int` for the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit off-topic but the good way to get the number of digit is using math.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int number = 123456;
    std::cout 
        << "Number of digit for '" << number << "' is '" 
        << std::ceil(std::log10(number)) << "'" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Computing the string is a heavy operation.

Comment: *but the good way to get the number of digit* -- It is not a "good way", especially since you are using floating point functions.

Comment: True better to look at that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151548/get-the-number-of-digits-in-an-int

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this isn't needed to be converted to string and then count the number of digits.
There are two ways to do this.

Step 1: Using loop.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int videoLengthMs = 123456;
    int numberLength = 0;
    int x = videoLengthMs; 
    while(x>0)
    {
       numberLength+=1;
       x= x/10;
    }
    cout<<"The length of the number is:"<<numberLength;
    return 0;
}
```

Step 2:
Using log to the base 10:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
  int videoLengthMs = 123456;
  cout<<"The length of the number is:"<< floor(log10(videoLengthMs)) + 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Don't do this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie especially in concert with [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).