# Can I find the number of digits of a BigInteger in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, biginteger

I am solving [this problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=25), in which they ask for the index of the first Fibonacci number of 1000 digits, and my first idea was something similar to:

```
BigInteger x = 1;
BigInteger y = 1;
BigInteger tmp = 0;

int currentIndex = 2;
while (x.NoOfDigits < 1000)
{
    tmp = x + y;
    y = x;
    x = tmp;
    currentIndex++;
}
return currentIndex;
```

However, as far as I can tell, there is no method for counting the number of digits of a BigInteger. Is this true? One way of circumventing it is to use the .ToString().Length method of a BigInteger, but I'm told that string processing is slow.

A BigInteger also has a .ToByteArray(), and I thought of converting a BigInteger to a byte array and checking the length of that array - but I don't think that this uniquely determines the number of digits in the BigInteger.

For what it's worth, I implemented another way of solving it, which is manually storing the Fibonacci numbers in array, and which stops as soon as the array is full, and I compared this to the .ToString-based method, which is about 2.5 times slower, but the first method takes 0.1 second, which also seems like a long time.

Edit: I've tested the two suggestions in the answers below (the one with BigInteger.Log and the one with MaxLimitMethod). I get the following run times:

- Original method: 00:00:00.0961957
- StringMethod: 00:00:00.1535350
- BigIntegerLogMethod: 00:00:00.0387479
- MaxLimitMethod: 00:00:00.0019509

Program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();
        clock.Start();
        int index1 = Algorithms.IndexOfNDigits(1000);
        clock.Stop();
        var elapsedTime1 = clock.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine(index1);
        Console.WriteLine("Original method: {0}",elapsedTime1);
        Console.ReadKey();

        clock.Reset();
        clock.Start();
        int index2 = Algorithms.StringMethod(1000);
        clock.Stop();
        var elapsedTime2 = clock.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine(index2);
        Console.WriteLine("StringMethod: {0}", elapsedTime2);
        Console.ReadKey();

        clock.Reset();
        clock.Start();
        int index3 = Algorithms.BigIntegerLogMethod(1000);
        clock.Stop();
        var elapsedTime3 = clock.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine(index3);
        Console.WriteLine("BigIntegerLogMethod: {0}", elapsedTime3);
        Console.ReadKey();

        clock.Reset();
        clock.Start();
        int index4 = Algorithms.MaxLimitMethod(1000);
        clock.Stop();
        var elapsedTime4 = clock.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine(index4);
        Console.WriteLine("MaxLimitMethod: {0}", elapsedTime4);
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}

static class Algorithms
{
    //Find the index of the first Fibonacci number of n digits
    public static int IndexOfNDigits(int n)
    {
        if (n == 1) return 1;
        int[] firstNumber = new int[n];
        int[] secondNumber = new int[n];

        firstNumber[0] = 1;
        secondNumber[0] = 1;
        int currentIndex = 2;

        while (firstNumber[n-1] == 0)
        {
            int carry = 0, singleSum = 0;
            int[] tmp = new int[n]; //Placeholder for the sum
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
            {
                singleSum = firstNumber[i] + secondNumber[i];
                if (singleSum >= 10) carry = 1;
                else carry = 0;

                tmp[i] += singleSum % 10;
                if (tmp[i] >= 10)
                {
                    tmp[i] = 0;
                    carry = 1;
                }
                int countCarries = 0;
                while (carry == 1)
                {
                    countCarries++;
                    if (tmp[i + countCarries] == 9)
                    {
                        tmp[i + countCarries] = 0;
                        tmp[i + countCarries + 1] += 1;
                        carry = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tmp[i + countCarries] += 1;
                        carry = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
            {
                secondNumber[i] = firstNumber[i];
                firstNumber[i] = tmp[i];
            }
            currentIndex++;
        }
        return currentIndex;
    }

    public static int StringMethod(int n)
    {
        BigInteger x = 1;
        BigInteger y = 1;
        BigInteger tmp = 0;
        int currentIndex = 2;

        while (x.ToString().Length < n)
        {
            tmp = x + y;
            y = x;
            x = tmp;
            currentIndex++;
        }
        return currentIndex;
    }

    public static int BigIntegerLogMethod(int n)
    {
        BigInteger x = 1;
        BigInteger y = 1;
        BigInteger tmp = 0;
        int currentIndex = 2;

        while (Math.Floor(BigInteger.Log10(x) + 1) < n)
        {
            tmp = x + y;
            y = x;
            x = tmp;
            currentIndex++;
        }
        return currentIndex;
    }

    public static int MaxLimitMethod(int n)
    {
        BigInteger maxLimit = BigInteger.Pow(10, n - 1);
        BigInteger x = 1;
        BigInteger y = 1;
        BigInteger tmp = 0;
        int currentIndex = 2;

        while (x.CompareTo(maxLimit) < 0)
        {
            tmp = x + y;
            y = x;
            x = tmp;
            currentIndex++;
        }
        return currentIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you get the size in base 10 by computing `log_10(number)` and ceil the result? Edit: I meant to it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1489928/5296568 . However, be carefull if you really want to compute the `log_10` of big numbers. String processing *may* be faster. Do benchmarks to confirm this.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thanks. The only Log10 I can find is Math.Log10, which takes a double as input, and I seem to get numerical problems, when I convert my BigInteger to a double. Maybe I can implement my own Log10.

Comment: No, there's a static function `BigInteger.Log(BigInteger num, double base)` right here: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd268364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You should also take a note of the other answers posted in the question above, but above *all* things what you should do is **benchmark** everything. The results can be suprising. Maybe, `.ToString().Length` **is** the fastest method.

Comment: @HowDoICSharply The simple way to compute the number of digits is to just keep dividing by 10 until the number is less than 10.  The number of times you divided + 1 is the number of digits.

Comment: @Kyle--that doesn't sound very efficient.  On a 1000 digit number, you'd have 1000 divisions just to find the length.  An alternative way addressing the problem, and in my opinion the fastest (though benchmark tests would be needed), would be to instead of checking the number of digits, set a constant for 10^n, where n is your number of  digits (n = 1000), and perform the operations until the sum is greater than that constant.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt thanks, I didn't look the right place. I ran all the suggestions in the comments, together with my original method and the .ToString().Length version. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Provided that x > 0

```
int digits = (int)Math.Floor(BigInteger.Log10(x) + 1);
```

will get the number of digits.

Out of curiosity, I tested the

```
int digits = x.ToString().Length;
```

approach. For 100 000 000 iterations, it's 3 times slower than the Log10 solution.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Only 3 times as slow? That is not bad for a routine that must divide by 10 so often.

Comment: Warning - this method is not always correct. 
(int)Math.Floor(BigInteger.Log10(1000) + 1) is 3 but the expected result is 4.
The reason is that BigInteger.Log10 only provides approximate results.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on my comment--instead of testing based on number of digits, test based on exceeding a constant that has the upper limit of the problem:

```
public static int MaxLimitMethod(int n)
    {
        BigInteger maxLimit = BigInteger.Pow(10, n);
        BigInteger x = 1;
        BigInteger y = 1;
        BigInteger tmp = 0;
        int currentIndex = 2;

        while (x.CompareTo(maxLimit) < 0)
        {
            tmp = x + y;
            y = x;
            x = tmp;
            currentIndex++;
        }
        return currentIndex;
    }
```

This should result in a significant performance increase.

Comment: Thanks. I've tested your solution. For some reason, I don't see an increased performance. It appears to be comparable to the log-method.

Comment: Wait a minute, I didn't realize the Stopwatch worked like an actual stopwatch. I have to reset it before I start it again. Your method is by far the fastest. I've edited my post to reflect the new times.

Comment: Yep.  It's an order of magnitude faster--because there is no math involved in figuring out if you've gone far enough or not.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

This is an even quicker method on .NET 5 (since `GetBitLength()` is required):

```
private static readonly double exponentConvert = Math.Log10(2);
private static readonly BigInteger _ten = 10;

public static int CountDigits(BigInteger value)
{
    if (value.IsZero)
        return 1;

    value = BigInteger.Abs(value);

    if (value.IsOne)
        return 1;

    long numBits = value.GetBitLength();

    int base10Digits = (int)(numBits * exponentConvert).Dump();
    var reference = BigInteger.Pow(_ten, base10Digits);

    if (value >= reference)
        base10Digits++;

    return base10Digits;
}
```

The slowest part of this algorithm for large values is the `BigInteger.Pow()` operation. I have optimized the `CountDigits()` method in [Singulink.Numerics.BigIntegerExtensions](https://github.com/Singulink/Singulink.Numerics.BigIntegerExtensions) with a cache that holds powers of 10, so check that out if you are interested in the fastest possible implementation. It caches powers up to exponents of 1023 by default but if you want to trade memory usage for faster performance on even larger values you can increase the max cached exponent by calling `BigIntegerPowCache.GetCache(10, maxSize)` where `maxSize = maxExponent + 1`.

On an i7-3770 CPU, this library takes 350ms to get the digit count for 10 million `BigInteger` values (single-threaded) when the digit count <= the max cached exponent.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

The accepted answer is unreliable, as indicated in the comments. This method works for all numbers:

```cs
private static int CountDigits(BigInteger value)
{    
    if (value.IsZero)
        return 1;
        
    value = BigInteger.Abs(value);
    
    if (value.IsOne)
        return 1;
    
    int exp = (int)Math.Ceiling(BigInteger.Log10(value));
    var test = BigInteger.Pow(10, exp);
    
    return value >= test ? exp + 1 : exp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
BigInteger bigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("12345678901234567890");

long bitLength = bigInteger.GetBitLength();//represents the length in binary
long decimalDigitCount = (long)Math.Ceiling(bitLength / 3.3219280948873623478703194294893);
Console.WriteLine("bigInteger is " + decimalDigitCount + "digits");
```

`3.3219280948873623478703194294893` is a constant value of ln(10) / ln(2) and we use it for converting binary to decimal.

I used google's gemini AI for finding this solution. Also I think this way is faster than `BigInteger.Log10(x)` solution because it doesn't seem to do a math process on Biginteger. So if the number is very big, this way should be faster.