# Fastest way to get the first 5 digits of a BigInteger

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization, biginteger

Suppose `n` is a `BigInteger` and I want its first 5 digits. I'm thinking in 2 ways:

1. Dividing `n` by 10 log<sub>10</sub>(n)-5 times (so only the first 5 digits would remain).
2. Get the `Substring(0, 5)` of `n`'s string.

I have no idea which one is faster or if there is another option that may be better than these.

I would like to hear considerations about it before I test these options (what do you think of them, if there is something better, etc.).

Comment: The first division/modulus option should outperform the string option, as creating strings (and taking substrings) tends to be costly.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34052627/4406995) tested with strings and log10 and found the strings solution to be 3 times slower (although they were trying to do 2 different things)

Comment: @Hayden, in the link you sent, could you understand Russ' answer? I don't see how he evaluates the number of digits of a BigInteger (and his answer seemed the fastest) since his function receives an integer.

Comment: Russ's answer receives an integer for the *number* of the digit, the evaluated BigInteger is created from there. You can skip it and take the BigInteger from parameter.

Comment: `BigInteger.TryFormat(Span ...` would avoid the string allocation.

Comment: The fastest is likely to involve `BigInteger.TryWriteBytes()` & some math, so you can stop when the next byte can't cause the answer to round up. But is it worth it?

Comment: Why don't you perf test your solutions? You've been waiting long enough for an answer that you could have tested it yourself by now?

Comment: `int result = (int)(value / BigInteger.Pow(10, (int)(value.GetBitLength() * 0.30102999566398 - 4)));` returns `5` or `6` digits integer; if we have `6` digits divide it by `10`: `if (result >= 1_000_000 || result < -1_000_000) result /= 10;`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko feel free to post it as an answer. I'd like to understand a bit of these magic numbers.

Comment: As `BigInteger` is not optimized for this operation in the slightest, if you are actually interested in performing this operation quickly it might be worth considering maintaining these digits separately, with a type that *is* suited to reading off decimal digits quickly (`decimal`). Of course `decimal` can't hold all the digits a `BigInteger` can, but depending on the kind of calculation you're doing it may be possible to maintain/recalculate the first digits on every operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to find out first **5** leading digits, we can exploit integer division:

```
   123     / 1   == 123
   12345   / 1   == 12345
   1234567 / 100 == 12345
```

Naive approach is to divide original value by `10` while it is bigger or equal `1_000_000`:

```
   1234567 => 123456 => 12345
```

However, division is expensive especially if we have a huge number (if we have a number with ~1000000 digits we have to divide this number ~1000000 times). To create a faster solution
we can compute an appropriate power of `10` (power computation is fast) and then divide just once:

```
  1234567 / Pow(10, Log10(1234567) - 5 + 1)
```

So the raw idea is

```
  result = source / BigInteger.Pow(10, (int)BigInteger.Log10(source) - 4);
```

There are two difficulties here:

1. Negative numbers (we should take absolute value of `source` at least when we computing logarithms)
2. Rounding errors for huge `source` (what if we have rounding up and have just `4` digits?)

To cope with both problems I compute `Log10` myself as `Log10(2) * Log2(source)`:

```
  value.GetBitLength() * 0.30102999566398
```

this guarantees that I have at *least* `5` digits but may be `6` in case of rounding errors (note `0.30102999566398 < Log10(2)`).

Combining all together:

```
private static int FirstDigits(BigInteger value) {
  if (value.IsZero)
    return 0; 

  int digits = 5;

  int result = (int)(value / 
    BigInteger.Pow(10, (int)(value.GetBitLength() * 0.30102999566398 - digits + 1)));

  while (result >= 1_000_000 || result <= -1_000_000)
    result /= 10;  

  return result;   
}
```