# Find Number of digits including 00000

Tags: c++, digits

I have to input a five digit card # I tried this but realized 00000 wouldn't work

```
if(credit_card_number > 99999)
          {
             cout << "CREDIT CARD NOT VALID TRY AGAIN TO MANY DIGITS\n";
             credit_card_valid = 0;
          }
          else if(credit_card_number < 10000)
          {
             cout << "CREDIT CARD NOT VALID TRY AGAIN NOT ENOUGH DIGITS\n";
             credit_card_valid = 0;
```

how would I make it where 00000 through 09999 is a valid card #

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to determine number of digits in an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489830/efficient-way-to-determine-number-of-digits-in-an-integer)

Comment: 00000 (or anything else starting with a 0) isn't an integer, so `credit_card_number` can't be an int.

Comment: @Juhana how would i make it 00000 a valid option make it a string?

Comment: You'll have to make it a string and check that it has exactly 5 characters and contains only numbers.

Comment: @Juhana Octal numeric literals start with 0.  Of course, octal  won't solve the OP's issue.

Comment: @Juhana Thanks ill try that

Comment: @Paul Only in certain programming languages, not in the real world.

Comment: Well, just to inform the OP that code *could* compile if they had integer literals starting with 0, but the code would not work as the OP would have expected.

Comment: Since you do not need to do arithmetic operations on that number and you need to keep front zeros, you should not  use integral type like `int`, but `std::string` instead and use regular expressions or other string methods to validate

Answer (score 0):

Input your credit card number as a string (look up `std::string` in the standard header `<string>`.    Then check if it is in the required format.

Since a real credit card number is represented using a set of integer values (notionally separated by spaces), this will work.

To check if a grouping of five characters is all digits, simply check it has length `5`, then check if each individual character in that grouping is a digit.     Look up `std::isdigit()` in either `<cctype>` or (more advanced) `<locale>`) - those two headers provide different overloads, for use in different contexts.

Comment: how do i use isdigit()

Comment: Use a loop to check the value of `isdigit()` for each character.   Read the documentation to understand arguments `isdigit()` will accept, and what it returns.

Comment: what would i type to check each char

Comment: I am not going to write code for you, unless you demonstrate genuine effort of your own.   Do your own homework.

Comment: lol its homework  but he hasnt went over what ever or however to use isdigit()

Comment: im genuinly confused

Answer (score 0):

Here valid will be equal to 1 if the string contain 5 digits.

```cpp
std :: string num = "00000";

int valid = num.size() == 5 and 
        std :: all_of(num.cbegin(), num.cend(), [](const char c){ return isdigit(c); });

printf("%d", valid); // 1
```