# Making structured (even) spaces in C++ for displaying data

Tags: c++

I've created a program that displays multiplication table:

```
for (int a=1; a<=10; a++)
{
    cout << endl;
    for (int b=1; b<=10; b++)
    {
        cout << " [" << a*b <<"]   ";
    }
}
```

The problem is it displays it like this:

[image: img]

I've tried to use setw() but it doesn't work since it sets it to all the numbers so it just makes the result spaced out a little bit more. Anything else i can try?

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors, shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Please [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: maybe using tab special character `\t` will work for you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry, I've never used this site before and didn't know that.

Comment: You either need to use tab characters (which then depends on terminals settings, since tabs can be set) or work out the width of `a*b` and subsequently output a number of space characters based on that width  (e.g. if `a*b` is one digit, the number of spaces to be output before/after it will be one more than would be the case if `a*b` has two digits).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) you will note that you need to stream it to your stream like so:

```
cout  << " [" << setw(3) << a*b <<"]   ";
```

[Here is a live example.](https://ideone.com/qdV7ya)

If you need to calculate the size that you need for the stream width, you can look up a question like this:

[Efficient way to determine number of digits in an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489830/efficient-way-to-determine-number-of-digits-in-an-integer)