# weird array syntax

Tags: php, syntax, arrays

I'm trying to figure how a function I've been given works -- or rather doesn't work. The problematic areas include array notation like this:

```
$small[$end[$i]{0}]
```

I *think* the idea is to append "0" to the value of `$end[$i]` and use that for the index of $small. But it doesn't work in PHP5.3.  Is this a deprecated syntax and is it trying to do what I think it is?

Comment: doesn't work as in "php breaks with a syntax error" or doesn't work as in "what should happen isn't happening"?

Comment: "Note: String s may also be accessed using braces, as in $str{42}, for the same purpose. However, this syntax is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. Use square brackets instead, such as $str[42]." http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @Lo'oris: `$end[$i]{0}` seems to be evaluating to null or ''.

Comment: @Tom Haigh: now that you've pointed it out, I do remember strings being accessible this way. Turns out though, that if the string is a number, it doesn't work. e.g. `$foo=200; $foo[0]!=2;` I think the solution is to replace the syntax with `substr($foo,1);`

Comment: @dnagirl: "$foo=200;" that isn't a string. using substr() is maybe slower and only works because the int is implicitly converted to a string.

Comment: @Tom Haigh: Since `$foo=200; $foo[0] != 2;//==''`, what do you recommend for getting the leftmost digit when the magnitude of the number is unknown?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's getting the first character from the `$end[$i]` string and then accessing the `$small` array using that character as the array key.

#### Edit:

> Since `$foo=200; $foo[0] != 2;//==''`,
>   what do you recommend for getting the
>   leftmost digit when the magnitude of
>   the number is unknown?

The easiest way is `substr($foo, 0, 1)` in PHP.

If you're using a strongly typed language, I have some metrics you may be interested in reading from another answer of mine: [How can you get the first digit in an int (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701322/how-can-you-get-the-first-digit-in-an-int-c/701621#701621)

Comment: thanks for correcting my understanding of what it's trying to do. B