# How would you pull the first number in a set of numbers while dropping the rest?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the number 123456789.

```
int x = 123456789;
```

I want to run a method that whenever that number changes it pulls the first number and puts it in an array.

An example would be say the number changes to reverse order.

The array should end with :

```
int[] arrayX = [1, 9];
```

Currently, I cannot get it to even pull the first number in the array correctly, much less do it when it changes.

My Code:

```
char[] Array1; //this is the array the "letter" would return into// 

static char Code(double Total, out char letter)
{
    string holder = Total.ToString();
    int[] numbers = new int[holder.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(holder.CharAt(i));
                                        //Errors at "CharAt"//
    }
    letter = numbers[0];
             
    return letter;
}
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Edit: letter = numbers[0] issue resolved.

Edit 2:  Thank you all for the responses, I will give a bit of clarity.

I want the method to pull the first number in X (starting would be 1)
and put it into arrayX at position 0, arrayX[0].

The method would run every time the number X changes.  It would then return the first number in X  (which will be "Total") and place it in the array at the next position available.

arrayX[1] = Total.ToString()[0];

and so on, for each change to X.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: [`CharAt` is not a method of `string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-5.0#methods) did you copy-pasta this code from Java? Just use `holder[i]` I haven't the faintest idea why you would want to convert it to `int` and back to `char` (if you did, do you want the Unicode codepoint or the equivalent number?). Or why you would want to put it all into an array, ignore it all and only return the first value. Or why you need the `out` param. You could just make the whole function `return Total.ToString()[0]`

Comment: Thank you, I will be needing the entire array later, but currently I just want to get this one part working as intended before I push on.  The numbers in the array will be changing positions and I just need the first one at specific times.

Comment: "Need the entire array" which array? `Array1` or `numbers`? Further points: You probably want a `List` for `Array1` not an array. `Convert.ToInt32('5')` returns 53 not 5. If that is what you wanted then you can do this much quicker `int[] numbers = Total.ToString().ToArray()` If you actually wanted the digit, then either use `int.Parse` or better: avoid strings entirely and do simple division by 10, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701322/how-can-you-get-the-first-digit-in-an-int-c

Comment: Eventually I will need both, currently I need the Total number in array form so I can access each number individually, but you assists with a quicker way to do that so I am grateful you helped me kill like 18 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you have to use integer array, if you can directly charAt to the string you have initialize inside the method.

```
  static char Code(double Total)
    {
        string holder = Total.ToString();
        return holder.CharAt(0); // or equivalent to return holder[0];
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701322/how-can-you-get-the-first-digit-in-an-int-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

also helpful info for those who ended up here because they are also starting out coding.